# Store any JoinHandle<> variant

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to hold join handles to any async function, in order to abort them when `ctrl+c` is given in my cli application (Have noticed async functions continue to run after `ctrl+c`)

I want a taskmanager which i can use in my exit handler to abort any running async tasks, but how do i store any joinhandle? using `JoinHandle<dyn std::any::Any>` throws:

> the size for values of type `(dyn Any + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

So how do I store any joinhandle?

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

use tokio::task::JoinHandle;

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: HashMap<String, JoinHandle<_>>
}
```

Comment: If you'll exit the application all tasks will be aborted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your `#[tokio::main] async fn main()` returns, all tasks are automatically aborted and the program terminates.  Aborting all outstanding tasks by hand isn't necessary, unless you want to ensure they are aborted before you do something else; if you plan on having your program terminate after aborting all outstanding tasks, just return from `main()`.

However, if you still want some way to manually abort tasks, there's a few options.

The simplest, if you *only* need the ability to abort tasks, is to store a closure that invokes `JoinHandle::abort()` instead of storing the `JoinHandle` itself.  For example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: HashMap<String, Box<dyn FnOnce()>>,
}

impl TaskManager {
    pub fn abort_all(&mut self) {
        for (_, abort) in self.tasks.drain() {
            abort();
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add_task<T: 'static>(&mut self, key: String, handle: JoinHandle<T>) {
        self.tasks.insert(key, Box::new(move || handle.abort()));
    }
}
```

A more complicated approach that allows you to do other things than abort tasks would be to write a trait with methods mirroring those of `JoinHandle`.  This allows you to "erase" knowledge of the `T` generic argument of `JoinHandle`.

In this example, the trait is `ErasedJoinHandle`.  Here I show `abort` defined on this trait, but you could add other methods from `JoinHandle` as well.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: HashMap<String, Box<dyn ErasedJoinHandle>>,
}

trait ErasedJoinHandle {
    fn abort(&self);
}

impl<T> ErasedJoinHandle for JoinHandle<T> {
    fn abort(&self) {
        JoinHandle::abort(self);
    }
}

impl TaskManager {
    pub fn abort_all(&mut self) {
        for (_, handle) in self.tasks.drain() {
            handle.abort();
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add_task<T: 'static>(&mut self, key: String, handle: JoinHandle<T>) {
        self.tasks.insert(key, Box::new(handle));
    }
}
```